# CSS Style for Checkboxes

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Is it possible to style the HTML checkbox without using javascripts? 
This code for example will work fine with IE, but not on Firefox or Chrome.
http://jsfiddle.net/5wJxF/
Any suggestions?

Comment: You should paste your code here also

Comment: I'm not sure about "without using javascript". The common approach is replacing html checkbox with a custom "checkbox" with help of javascript. The example of this way is variety of jQuery plugins, for instance, http://alt-checkbox.starikovs.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

YES. It **is** possible.

You can't directly style the checkbox element, but the effect you're looking for can be achieved if you use a `<label>` element in conjunction with the checkbox, and style that.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="field1" class="mycheckbox" />
<label for="field1" class="mycheckbox-label">Label here</label>
```

And then your CSS would look like this:

```
.mycheckbox {
  display:none;
}

.mycheckbox + label {
  padding:20px; /*or however wide your graphic is*/
  background:url(/fancy-unchecked.gif) no-repeat left center;
}

.mycheckbox:checked + label {
  background:url(/fancy-checked.gif) no-repeat left center;
}
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/TVaPX/ (tested with Firefox 5)

The trouble with this approach is that it only works in modern browsers. Older browsers may not support the `:checked` or `+` CSS selectors. But if you're okay with not supporting older versions of IE, then this will work. The example above does not work in IE8 (it supports `+` but not `:checked`).

If you're not comfortable with that, then you'll have to stick with a Javascript solution.

However, with an approach similar to this, you can still do it with very minimal amounts of Javascript code: simply have a one-line JS that toggles the class of the checkbox when it's checked, and you can use all the above code, but with the alternate classname instead of the `:checked` selector. That will work in IE7 and IE8.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 for using jsFiddle's images :) however, as the question mentions cross-browser compatibility, perhaps the answer should be "NO".

Comment: @Bad: Well, technically it does work in IE... IE9 that is. He didn't actually specify which versions he wanted to support ;) But you're right of course, IE8 is the minimum realistic standard one needs to support these days (possibly IE7 or even IE6 if your boss is masochistic). But I was careful to explain the caveats and give a minimalist JS solution that uses the same basic approach for older browsers.  :)  Using Modernizr or similar, you could of course check for compatibility before deciding whether to use pure CSS or the JS solution. But of course, Modernizr itself is a JS solution. heh.

Comment: This did not work for me in IE7. It only seems to work if the input is anything but display: none;

Comment: @sway - you  could try `visibility:hidden;` instead, I guess. Not quite the same, but worth trying?

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not possible. The appearance of the checkboxes is OS- and browser-specific. Only JavaScript-based solutions let you style them in a way that will work across all browsers.

You might like [this plugin](http://uniformjs.com/). It's easy to use and gives satisfying results.

Answer (score 3):

You can style it with CSS3(Chrome or Safari only!), but for anything esle - no other way that js.

There are 40+ examples here: [FORMS ENHANCEMENTS DEMOS](http://www.noupe.com/css/form-elements-40-cssjs-styling-and-functionality-techniques.html)

There are some plug ins - I used to use [jNice](http://www.whitespace-creative.com/jquery/jNice/) - not just pure CSS3 for modern browser and standard checkbox/dropdown for anything else.

Best Regards,

Pete